# DispatcherTimer for many view models

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We have a WPF application with many viewmodels. Basically they contain formatted date time strings which have to be updated periodically.

What is the best solution for this?

- a dispatcher timer instance for every view model instance
- one shared dispatcher timer
- a shared Rx interval

I have the feeling that the first solution is the worst but don't know how to proof this.

Comment: can you provide some context? How tecnology (winform, webforms, wpf, mvc, ...) you using?

Comment: The WPF application consists of many viewmodels which are bound dynamically to their respective views via Caliburn Micro's MVVM framework.

Comment: I'd go for Rx, where all your viewmodels subscribe to the same sequence

Comment: best solution is the one that will satisfy you application requirements so the decision of one time V"S many should be based on your update needs. I would just pick one and see where it gets me

Comment: Are they all updated at the same time/interval?

Comment: Post some relevant code. And no, I would not tie my ViewModels to any Dispatcher of any kind, and use regular `System.Threading.Timer`s instead.